# Jsoup selecting only text within a div with other elements

Tags: java, css, parsing, jsoup, selector

I have `div` with a lot of inner mumbo jumbo like this:

```
<div>sometext

   <p>

   </p>sometext

   <div>

   </div>sometext

</div>
```

and I need to choose the text that is in the parent `div` without all the text in the children elements. I cannot use `.not()` to get rid of the divs inside. I cannot get the children elements either because it eliminates the text inside and returns only the inside elements. So basically I need the text only without any of the children elements.

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you really have text like `[div]` or is it `<div>` but you used `[` and `]` instead of `<` and `>` to print your example here?

Comment: did you try to remove all children? and then get text(). OR use ownText();

Comment: poist actual markup and check your tags - java or javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you need to use the `yourElement.ownText();`

as the Jsoup's doc states:

**String    ownText()**: Gets the text owned by this element only; does not get the combined text of all children.

Comment: Thank you very much. Wonderful people of stackoverflow